# What are two typical threshold voltages for a flash FET?

Tags: flash, nand-flash

I have a simple question for you all: what is a realistic approximation of a pair of threshold voltages for a flash transistor? I am working with NAND flash, 45nm, with VDD = 0.8V. I can find lots of information on the basics of flash, and scientific papers on applications etc, but no mention of specific threshold voltages used.

Any tips you can give me to help solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!